# Mongodb iso time not showing properly

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2010-01-15 00:00:00"));
echo $start;
```

I am converting current php time to mongodb iso time.
when I echo $start, i get **0.00000000** 1263493800.

how to get only 1263493800. I dont need the 0.00000000 part

Comment: Have you tried calling the `sec` property like this `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start->sec);`?

Comment: @chridam, yes i had also done that.